# Implement a clear button for a custom input field to trigger required error with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

**Expectation**

React Hook form should show the error message when we clear the input field with a cross button

**Issues**

1. Required error message not shown after the value is cleared with the cross button.
2. After clearing value with cross button submit button is not disabled.

### Code for the Custom Input Field

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export default function MyInput(props) {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const clear = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.value = '';
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputRef} {...props} />
      {/* I want to trigger the required error of react hook form on clear*/}
      <button onClick={clear} style={{
        marginLeft: '-1.2rem',
        cursor: 'pointer'
      }}>x</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

### Usage in the form

```
          <Controller
            name="firstName"
            control={control}
            rules={{
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: 'You must enter your first name'
              }
            }}
            render={({ field: { ref, ...rest } }) => <CustomInput {...rest} />}
          />
```

Not sure if `useRef` is the right way to go, but I want to use an uncontrolled input that I want to customize with a clear button

**Link to Stackblitz - [Custom Input with clear Button](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-custom-input-clear-button-stackoverflow-react-hook-form?file=src/App.js)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to let the form know about the change on click of the clear button is to call the `setValue` method from the `useForm` hook to register the change manually.

So, I can pass setValue as a prop to my child component i.e. the Custom Input
and set the new value on the click event of the clear button of the input field

```
  const clear = () => {
    setValue(name, '', { 
      shouldValidate: true, 
      shouldDirty: true 
    });
  }
```

Also `useRef` is not required for this use case.

**Link to Updated Stackblitz - [Custom Input with clear Button](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-custom-input-clear-button-setvalue-react-hook-form?file=src/CustomInput.jsx)**